# count of active contacts and inactive contact related to account

Tags: trigger

I have created a custom checkbox "ACTIVE" on contact.
 Now i want to display the number of active/ inactive contacts on acount page.

Can this be done w/o using code.

Looking for an approach

```
if(trigger.isDelete){
        system.debug('-------------trigger.old----------> '+trigger.old);
        if( trigger.old!= null){
            for(Contact con : trigger.old){
                system.debug('-----------con----------> '+con);                
                lstAccId.add( con.accountId );
            }



        for ( account acc : [select id, Count_of_Active_Contacts__c, Count_of_Inactive_Contacts__c from account where id in : lstAccId]){

            for(contact con : trigger.old){
                if(con.accountId == acc.id){
                    if(con.active__C = TRUE){
                         if (acc.Count_of_Active_Contacts__c != Null){
                            acc.Count_of_Active_Contacts__c = acc.Count_of_Active_Contacts__c - 1 ;
                         }
                    }
                    else{
                        if (acc.Count_of_Inactive_Contacts__c != Null){
                            acc.Count_of_Inactive_Contacts__c = acc.Count_of_Inactive_Contacts__c  -1;
                        }
                    }
                } 
            }
            lstAcc.add(acc);
        }
        update lstAcc;
         }
    }
```

wrote the following but getting an error " System.FinalException: Record is read-only: Trigger.updateActiveStatusInAccounts: line 93, column 1""

Although isupdate and is insert works fine for me

thanks
ankita

Comment: Use process builder to fire on creation or edit of a contact and have it update number fields on the account record. Play around with it, this should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: I tried process builder but the i am not able to get what  i really want..i guess i have to write code only for this

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck, what have you tried? Update your question, post screenshots etc. I'm 99% sure you can achieve this all with 1 process, all point&click.

Comment: i have updated my question and i have also pasted the code and error i am getting

Comment: I see your issue, a process cannot be fired from deletion of a record (Contact in this case). I'm not a developer myself, so I cannot help you any further I'm afraid.

Comment: I got the error.it was at line " if(con.active__C = TRUE)" .it shoulf be like " if(con.active__C == TRUE)" .Thanks everyone for your help

Comment: @robindebondt - i would love to know how it can be achieved just by using point n click